# Basic unit test to check if I have read access to a field - Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, field-level-security

I'm currently working on a generic way of implementing FLS on all SOQL calls in my code base.

I want to start by creating a few basic unit tests in Apex to check whether or not I have read access to certain fields.

Could someone point me in the direction of some basic unit tests that could check whether or not I have access to a field?

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unit tests don't return error messages to VF pages. Everything is written to a log file.

Comment: Is this for a VF controller or a different context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question it looks like you want to check if a field is editable / createable by the current user. I think you can do this by using the `DescribeFieldResult` class. In the below example I have hardcoded the field which you can easily parameterize.

```
 Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.CustomerPriority__c.getDescribe();
 system.debug('Is the field Create-able '+ F.isCreateable()); 
 system.debug('Is the field Editable '+ f.isUpdateable());
```

Comment: This is what I immediately thought of when I saw this question. Once you have done the describe on the field, there is the "isAccessible" method which might respond with what you want? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isAccessible

Comment: Ah I see, much appreciated guys!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you start by working through the tutorials in the [VisualForce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm?language=en). There's a section covering controllers and controller extensions that includes test classes. You'll also want to look at the last section in particular of the [Apex Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm?language=en) which covers VF controllers and test classes for them.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, I appreciate the response. But I need to get somthing basic put together very quickly so I don't really have time to go through the docs.

Comment: So you want us to write your code for you? Here's a link to a good SF search engine: http://findsf.info/. Use the right combination of key words and you might find some code snippets in someone's blog or a link that will take you to code examples that are in the SF docs.

Comment: Absolutely not, even though it very much sounds that way. I was just hoping for a small example I could build upon. Thanks all the same crmprogdev.

Comment: My point being you could at least check the references provided to see if what you need is there rather than dismissing them entirely; especially since this is your first test class. Until you have a test user context, none of anyone else's code on how to detect FLS will be of use to you.